# Multiplication math game using classes/constructors

Tags: java

I've done some coding in the past but nothing with OOP and honestly, I cannot wrap my head around using classes and constructors to tidy up my code. I'm used to "calling functions" instead of pasting code over and over again but in Java, the methods and classes, etc. take care of that but man, I'm just not getting it.

My code is for a basic math game based on multiplication. I'd like to have two modes, one with elapsed time and one with a count-down timer. I've build most of the code (and it actually works) but it's to the point where it's getting super repetitive to add what I want to add because I'm coding the whole thing in the main method.

I'd love some help cleaning it up by putting all of the basic functions in separate classes such as askQuestion, checkAnswer, displayScoreMessage, displayQuestionLog, playAgain, etc.

My code is below and I tried to comment as I went.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

MY CODE:

```
package mathfactsGame;

import java.text.DecimalFormat; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mathfactsGameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set numbers to 0
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;

        long totalStart = 0;
        int mathfact = 0;
        // Create arraylist QuestionLog
        List<Object> questionLog = new ArrayList<Object>();

        // Start game loop
        while (true) {
            // Set score to 0
            int score = 0;
            // initialize scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Begin game
            System.out.println("MULTIPLICATION MATH FACTS GAME");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            // set name
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String playerName = input.next();
            // Set the mathfact family you want

            System.out.println("What MathFact family do you want do you want? (1-12)"); // Need to add an option for ALL
            int mathFact = input.nextInt();// in ALL option, mathFact would just be r.nextInt(13)
            // Greeting and choose count down mode or elapsed time mode
            System.out.println("Would you like to play challenge mode or timed mode?");
            System.out.println("1 = challenge");
            System.out.println("2 = timed"); // need to build timed mode -> when time ends, go to game score message and
                                                // print out questionLog
            int mode = input.nextInt();
            // User sets number of questions
            System.out.println("How many questions do you want?");
            int questions = input.nextInt();
            // Begin For loop, play game the number of times the user set with (questions)
            // count score (# right)
            // start timer
            totalStart = System.nanoTime();
            for (int count = 1; count <= questions; count++) {
                // Generate random numbers
                Random r = new Random();
                n1 = mathFact;
                n2 = r.nextInt(13);

                // Start timer for each question
                Long start = System.nanoTime();
                // check if answer is correct
                boolean resultOK = false;
                String displayResultOK = null;
// TIMED (mode 1) (Haven't written mode 2)
                if (mode == 1) {
                    System.out.println("\nQuestion #" + count);
                    System.out.println("What is " + n1 + " x " + n2 + "?");
                    int answer = input.nextInt();
                    // Check if answer is correct else it's incorrect
                    if (answer == (n1 * n2)) {
                        System.out.println("CORRECT");
                        score++;
                        resultOK = (n1 * n2 == answer);
                        displayResultOK = resultOK ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT";
                        long end = System.nanoTime();
                        double duration = end - start;
                        double totalDurationSec = duration / 1000000000d;
                        DecimalFormat formattingObject = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                        String roundedtotalDurationSec = formattingObject.format(totalDurationSec);
                        System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + roundedtotalDurationSec);
                        questionLog.add("Question #" + (count) + ":");
                        questionLog.add(n1 + " x " + n2);
                        questionLog.add("\tYour answer = " + answer);
                        questionLog.add("\tCorrect answer = " + (n1 * n2));
                        questionLog.add("\tYou got the answer " + displayResultOK);
                        questionLog.add("in " + roundedtotalDurationSec + " seconds\n");
                    }
                    // else for incorrect
                    else {
                        System.out.println("INCORRECT");

                        resultOK = (n1 * n2 == answer);
                        displayResultOK = resultOK ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT";
                        long end = System.nanoTime();
                        double duration = end - start;
                        double totalDurationSec = duration / 1000000000d;
                        DecimalFormat formattingObject = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                        String roundedtotalDurationSec = formattingObject.format(totalDurationSec);
                        questionLog.add("Question #" + (count) + ":");
                        questionLog.add(n1 + " x " + n2);
                        questionLog.add("\tYour answer = " + answer);
                        questionLog.add("\tCorrect answer = " + (n1 * n2));
                        questionLog.add("\tYou got the answer " + displayResultOK);
                        questionLog.add("in " + roundedtotalDurationSec + " seconds\n");
                        System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + roundedtotalDurationSec);

                    }

                }
            }
            // clean up questionLog formatting
            questionLog.add(0, "");
            String formattedString = questionLog.toString().replace(",", "") // remove the commas
                    .replace("[", "") // remove the right bracket
                    .replace("]", ""); // remove the left bracket

            // Calculate score messages
            if (score == questions) {
                // All correct
                System.out.println("\n===Question Log=== \n");
                System.out.println(formattedString);
                long totalEnd = System.nanoTime();
                long totalDuration = totalEnd - totalStart;
                double totalDurationALL = totalDuration / 1000000000d;
                DecimalFormat formattingObject = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                String roundedTotaltime = formattingObject.format(totalDurationALL);
                System.out.println("\nGreat Job! " + playerName + ", your score is " + score + " out of " + questions
                        + ", or 100%! You got them all correct in " + roundedTotaltime + " total seconds.\n");
            } else {
                // Any wrong
                System.out.println("\n===Question Log=== \n");
                System.out.println(formattedString);
                long totalEnd = System.nanoTime();
                long totalDuration = totalEnd - totalStart;
                double totalDurationALL = totalDuration / 1000000000d;
                DecimalFormat formattingObject = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                String roundedTotaltime = formattingObject.format(totalDurationALL);
                double percent = (((double) score / (double) questions)) * 100;
                String roundedPercent = formattingObject.format(percent);
                System.out.println("\n" + playerName + ", your score is " + score + " out of " + questions + ", or "
                        + roundedPercent + "%. You missed " + (questions - score) + " questions in " + roundedTotaltime
                        + " total seconds. \n");
            }

            // Play again?
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
            String again = input.next();
            questionLog.clear();
            // End loop if "N"
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                input.close();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

===EDITED TO ADD===

I understand I'm asking a lot so I've tried to do some more work to show some effort on my part but am getting stuck again.

I finally made some headway splitting off into a different class.

I have no idea how to build the question log and I cannot get the mathFact variable to work doing what I'm doing. It's always a random number.

Thanks again for looking and any help would be super useful!

Here's my Main method:

```
package game2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class game2main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("MULTIPLICATION MATH FACTS GAME");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String playerName = input.next();
            Question.mathFact();
            System.out.println("How many questions do you want?");
            int questions = input.nextInt();
            long totalStart = 0;
            totalStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++) {
                Question q = new Question();
                q.askQuestion();
                q.Check();
                Question.qTime();
            }
            Question.showScore();
            long totalEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double totalDuration = totalEnd - totalStart;
            double totalDurationSec = (totalDuration / 1000);
            System.out.println("Total time elapsed: " + totalDurationSec);
            // play again
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
            String again = input.next();
            if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                input.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Question class:

```
package game2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
    public static int mathFact = 0;
    public static int mode = 0;
    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    public String Question;
    private static long start = 0;
    private int correct;
    Random rand = new Random();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int score = 0;
    Question() {
        n1 = rand.nextInt(mathFact);
        n2 = rand.nextInt(13);
    }
    public void askQuestion() {
        System.out.println("What is " + n1 + " x " + n2 + " ?\n");
        correct = n1 * n2;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public static void qTime() {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double duration = end - start;
        double durationSec = (duration / 1000);
        System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + durationSec);
    }
    public void Check() {
        int response = input.nextInt();
        if (response == correct) {
            System.out.printf("yes.\n");
            score++;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("No. It is " + correct + ".\n");
        }
    }
    public static void showScore() {
        System.out.println("Number correct: " + score);
    }
    public static void mathFact() {
        System.out.println("What MathFact family do you want do you want? (1-12)");
        mathFact = input.nextInt();// in ALL option, mathFact would just be r.nextInt(13)
    }
    public void Mode() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play challenge mode or timed mode?");
        System.out.println("1 = challenge");
        System.out.println("2 = timed"); // need to build timed mode -> when time ends, go to game score message and print out questionLog
        mode = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that the title of your post is a description of what your code does, not what you need help with. For more assistance see [the help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I edited the title. Hopefully, that will suffice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your code.  Here's the result of a test run.

```
MULTIPLICATION MATH FACTS GAME
==============================
What is your name?
Gilbert
Would you like to play challenge mode or timed mode?
1 = challenge
2 = timed
2
What MathFact family do you want do you want? (1-12)
6
How many questions do you want?
3
What is 4 x 6 ?
24
Yes, you're correct.
Time elapsed: 3.641
What is 2 x 6 ?
12
Yes, you're correct.
Time elapsed: 4.103
What is 5 x 3 ?
15
Yes, you're correct.
Time elapsed: 3.32
Number correct: 3
Total time elapsed: 11.065
Would you like to play again? Y/N
n
Thank you Gilbert for playing!
```

Here are the major changes I made.

1. I eliminated all static fields and methods, except for the `main` method to start the application.  Generally, you don't use static methods or fields when creating a multi-class application.
2. I divided the code into a Main class and a Question class.  The Main class is responsible for all of the non-game interaction with the user.  The Question class generates the questions and checks the answers to the questions.  Generally, you try and put the responsibility for input/output in one class and an application model in a separate class.
3. The code I wrote goes from general at the top to more specific as I go down through the methods.  An understandable program is like an understandable essay.  Start with the main points, then add the details.
4. I created one instance of `Scanner`.  I passed that instance to the Question class.  Generally, your code should have one and only one `System.in` `Scanner`.
5. I created one instance of the Question class.
6. I named all the methods with a verb-noun combination.  Generally, that's what readers of your code expect.  This tells them what the method does.
7. Class names start with an upper-case letter.  Method names start with a lower-case letter.  Field names start with a lower-case letter.  This allows me to write `Question question = new Question(input);` and have the reading of that line make sense.

I didn't do anything with the mode value either.

Here's the complete runnable code I modified.  I made the Question class an inner class so I could copy and paste this code as one module.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplicationGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultiplicationGame().runGame();
    }

    private void runGame() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Question question = new Question(input);
        String playerName = getPlayerName(input);
        
        do {
            int mode = getMode(input);
            int mathfact = getMathFact(input);
            int questionCount = getTotalQuestionCount(input);
            askQuestions(question, mode, mathfact, questionCount);
        } while (playAgain(input, playerName));
        
        input.close();
    }

    private void askQuestions(Question question, int mode, 
            int mathfact, int questionCount) {
        question.setMode(mode);
        question.setMathFact(mathfact);
        question.setScore(0);
        
        long totalStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++) {
            question.askQuestion();
            question.checkAnswer();
            question.printQuitTime();
        }
        question.printScore();
        
        long totalEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double totalDuration = totalEnd - totalStart;
        double totalDurationSec = (totalDuration / 1000);
        System.out.println("Total time elapsed: " + totalDurationSec);
    }

    private String getPlayerName(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("MULTIPLICATION MATH FACTS GAME");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        return input.nextLine();
    }
    
    private int getMode(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play challenge mode or timed mode?");
        System.out.println("1 = challenge");
        System.out.println("2 = timed");
        int mode = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        return mode;
    }
    
    private int getMathFact(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("What MathFact family do you want? (1-12)");
        int mathFact = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        return mathFact;
    }
    
    private int getTotalQuestionCount(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("How many questions do you want?");
        int questionCount = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        return questionCount;
    }
    
    private boolean playAgain(Scanner input, String playerName) {
        // play again
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Y/N");
        String again = input.nextLine();
        if (again.charAt(0) == 'n') {
            System.out.println("Thank you " + playerName + " for playing!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Question {
        private int correctAnswer;
        private int mathfact;
        private int mode;
        private int score;
        
        private long start;
        
        private final Random random;
        private final Scanner input;

        public Question(Scanner input) {
            this.input = input;
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        public void setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

        public void setMathFact(int mathfact) {
            this.mathfact = mathfact;
        }

        public void setMode(int mode) {
            this.mode = mode;
        }

        public void askQuestion() {
            int n1 = random.nextInt(mathfact) + 1;
            int n2 = random.nextInt(mathfact) + 1;
            System.out.println("What is " + n1 + " x " + n2 + " ?");
            correctAnswer = n1 * n2;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public void printQuitTime() {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double duration = end - start;
            double durationSec = (duration / 1000);
            System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + durationSec);
        }

        public void checkAnswer() {
            int response = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            if (response == correctAnswer) {
                System.out.println("Yes, you're correct.");
                score++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No. It is " + correctAnswer + ".");
            }
        }

        public void printScore() {
            System.out.println("Number correct: " + score);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helps a lot getting my head wrapped around everything. I appreciate it!